# How to show HTML text in TextView?

Tags: java, android, html, textview

how to show this html code in TextView. without any minimum API requirement

HTML CODE IS BELOW:

```
<h2>Hey !</h2>
<blockquote>
<h2>Hey !</h2>
<blockquote>
  <p>
    <span style="color: #0000ff;">
      hello world 
      <em>
        <strong>
          is a virtual world.
        </strong>
      </em>
    </span>
    
  </p>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: Use `Html.fromHtml()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare sir, your detail is not enough for a beginner. but now i got it. btw tysm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Solution.

```
package com.andro.coundowntimer;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.text.HtmlCompat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String htmlCode= "<h2>Hey !</h2>\n" +
                "<blockquote>\n" +
            "<p><span style=\"color: #0000ff;\">hello world <em><strong>is a virtual world.</strong></em></span>\uD83D\uDE02</p>\n" +
            "</blockquote>";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(htmlCode,0)); 
    }
}
```